# knockout won't bind to nested element

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I don't understand why I can successfully bind data to a particular div, but if I attempt the same exact binding to a nested element (I've tried several configurations of divs and spans), Knockout will no longer respond to any data change for the binding. I can't suss out a reason for this. Can anyone offer insight? Here are the two scenarios:

Successful binding:

```
<div id="header" data-bind="html: viewModel.chatInvites()"></div>
```

Non responsive:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="chatInvitesCount" data-bind="html: viewModel.chatInvites()"></div>
</div>
```

The reason I need this nested structure is that I am styling the outer div as a circle with the inner div as centered text (a graphic treatment).

Comment: can you add a bit more context. How and what are you changing in your model.

Comment: Second @Kieran, mentioned code will work fine, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ag5j/).

Comment: the fiddle is working for me. If i change a name it is reflected in the rendered divs at the top. Am i missing something.

Comment: @Kieran no you're not missing anything, by "second" I meant I agree with you, that we need more info (because, as per the fiddle, the posted code would work fine)

Comment: ah sorry friday afternoon i did not read the name on the post

Comment: You are both right, there is something going on here that needs more context in order to solve. That's been part of the difficulty for me, i.e. to try to suss what in the context is the issue. I will follow up with more information then. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Unfortunately, the context that is missing is buried in the internals of the framework that I am using (jqMobi). It inserts an <h1> tag with the header text and styles it. Something about that process is interfering with the rendering of the bound value display. The ko.computed function is in fact returning the value properly each time it changes, but original rendered value is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Do not use brakets on 'viewModel.chatInvites' cause this makes knockout to take the current value and do not update if the observable changes.

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="chatInvitesCount" data-bind="html: viewModel.chatInvites"></div>
</div>
```